# Commenting Core Data Model

Tags: core-data

Is there a way to add comments to the entities, attributes, and relationships in the data model for Core Data? As my model becomes more complex, it would be useful to have comments, but I haven't seen any way to do this. Of course, it would also be helpful if the comments can be retained through migrations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of adding comments directly to your Core Data model, but viewing the model in X-code you can switch to Table, Graph editor style in the lower right corner of the entity inspector. This view should serve plenty as documentation for your model if you've built it logically.

Of course you could always add a comment section in your App Delegate, covering the structure of your Core Data model, but I suppose you do know this alreay.